# Add Google Recaptcha on a SilverStripe form

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, silverstripe

I am trying to add Google Recaptcha to my custom SilverStripe form.

I have generated Google public and private keys but I do not know where to put them to show a captcha on my website.

Here is my current code:

**ContactPage**

```
class ContactPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'TelCustomerSupport'    => 'Varchar',
        'TelProjectSupport'     => 'Varchar',
        'OfficeName'            => 'Text',
        'OfficeStreetAddress'   => 'Text',
        'OfficeAddressLocality' => 'Text',
        'OfficePostalCode'      => 'Varchar',
        'OfficeMapLink'         => 'Text',
        'OfficeLatitude'        => 'Text',
        'OfficeLongitude'       => 'Text',
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        // Add extra fields
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('TelCustomerSupport', 'Phone - Customer, Trade & Retail Support'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('TelProjectSupport', 'Phone - Project Support'), "Content");

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeName'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeStreetAddress'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeAddressLocality'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficePostalCode'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeMapLink'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeLatitude'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeLongitude'), "Content");

        return $fields;
    }

}

class ContactPage_Controller extends NetSuitePage_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array('ContactForm');

    // Generate the form
    public function ContactForm()
    {
        // Create fields
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create("FirstName")->setTitle(_t('Contact.FIRSTNAME')),
            TextField::create("LastName")->setTitle(_t('Contact.LASTNAME')),
            EmailField::create("Email")->setTitle(_t('Contact.EMAILADDRESS')),
            TextField::create("Phone")->setTitle(_t('Contact.PHONENUMBER')),
            DropdownField::create('Iam', _t('Contact.IAMA'), $this->translateNetsuiteConfigArray('Contact', 'Iam')),
            TextField::create("SendSubject")->setTitle(_t('Contact.SUBJECT')),
            HoneyPotField::create("Subject2")->setTitle('Subject2'),
            TextareaField::create("Message")->setTitle(_t('Contact.MESSAGE'))->setColumns(30)->setRows(10)
        new RecaptchaField('MyCaptcha')
        );

        // Create actions
        $submitbutton = new FormAction('doContactForm', _t('Contact.SEND'));
        $submitbutton->addExtraClass('btn btn-black');
        $actions = new FieldList(
            $submitbutton
        );

        $validator = ZenValidator::create();
        $validator->addRequiredFields(array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Iam', 'SendSubject', 'Message'));
        $validator->setConstraint('FirstName', Constraint_length::create('max', 32));
        $validator->setConstraint('LastName', Constraint_length::create('max', 32));
        $validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_length::create('min', 7));
        $validator->setConstraint('Email', Constraint_type::create('email'));
        $validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_type::create('digits'));

        $form = new Form($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);
        $form->addExtraClass('contact-form');
        $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);

        return $form;
    }

    // Deal with form submission
    public function doContactForm($data, $form)
    {

        $submission = new ContactFormSubmission();
        $form->saveInto($submission);
        $submission->write();

        $data['path'] = print_r($this->refererTracker->retrieveAll(), true);

        $email = new Email();
        $email->setTemplate('ContactFormEmail');
        $email->populateTemplate($data);
        $email->setTo($this->getNetsuiteConfig('Contact', 'Emails'));
        $email->setFrom("no-reply@warmup.co.uk");
        $email->setSubject('[warmup.co.uk] New contact from the website');
        $email->populateTemplate($data);
        $email->send();

        $post = $this->getNetsuiteConfig('Contact');

        $post->firstname                    = $data['FirstName'];
        $post->lastname                     = $data['LastName'];
        $post->email                        = $data['Email'];
        $post->phone                        = $data['Phone'];
        $post->custentity116                = $data['Iam'];
        $post->custentitysubject_contact_us = $data['SendSubject'];
        $post->custentitymessage_contact_us = $data['Message'];


        // Check for success
        if ($this->queueNetSuitePost($post)) {
            return $this->redirect(Director::get_current_page()->Link()."?success=1");
        }

        // Redirect back with form data and error message
        Session::set('FormInfo.' . $form->FormName() . '.data', $data);
        Session::set('FormInfo.'.$form->FormName().'.errors', array());
        $form->sessionMessage("Netsuite error", 'bad');

        return $this->redirectBack();

    }

    // Returns true if form submitted successfully
    public function Success()
    {
        return isset($_REQUEST['success']) && $_REQUEST['success'] == "1";
    }

    public function getCurrentSubsite()
    {
        $subsite = Subsite::currentSubsite();

        if($subsite) {
            return $subsite->Title;
        }
        return $subsite;
    }

}
```

---

**ContactFormSubmission**

```
class ContactFormSubmission extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'FirstName' => 'Text',
        'LastName' => 'Text',
        'Email' => 'Text',
        'Phone' => 'Text',
        'Iam' => 'Text',
        'Subject' => 'Text',
        'Message' => 'Text'
    );
}
```

How do I correctly add Google Recaptcha to my form?

Comment: You're probably better off using a module like https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha instead of doing your own implementation.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, but can you help to make changes in above code to fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

We can add Google Nocaptcha to our form using the [SilverStripe Nocaptcha module](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha).

The easiest way to install this module is through `composer` with the following command:

```
composer require undefinedoffset/silverstripe-nocaptcha
```

After installing the module be sure to call `dev/build?flush=all`.

Next we must set the spam protector to `NocaptchaProtector` through our site config.yml file, as well as set the `Nocaptcha` keys.

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
# ...

FormSpamProtectionExtension:
  default_spam_protector: NocaptchaProtector

NocaptchaField:
  site_key: "YOUR_SITE_KEY"
  secret_key: "YOUR_SECRET_KEY"
```

The keys are retrieved through Google when setting up a [new `Nocaptcha` account](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).

Make sure to call `?flush=all` after adding these settings.

We are now ready to enable spam protection on our form. To do this we simply call `$form->enableSpamProtection()` in our form function:

```
public function ContactForm()
{
    // Create fields
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        // ...
    );

    // Create actions
    $actions = FieldList::create(
        // ...
    );

    $validator = ZenValidator::create();

    $form = Form::create($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);

    $form->enableSpamProtection();

    return $form;
}
```

Google Nocaptcha should now be enabled on our form.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
new LiteralField('recaptcha_bubble', '<div id="recaptcha_bubble" class="field"></div>')
```

in your forms field list
Then add the google javascript with

```
Requirements::javascript("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=en-GB");
```

After that add the function to your javascript

```
var recaptchaCallback = function () {
var elementExists = document.getElementById('recaptcha_bubble');
if (null != elementExists) {
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_bubble', {
        'sitekey' : 'the site key here'
    });
}};
```

When the form will be submitted with the variable 'g-recaptcha-response'

```
function getPostUrlContents($url, $fields){
    $result = null;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30;

    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, rtrim($fields_string, '&'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

public function checkGoogle_recaptcha_Response($code) {
    $result = $this->getPostUrlContents(
        'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        array(
            'secret' => urlencode('secret key here'),
            'response' => urlencode($code)
        )
    );
    if (!$result) return false;
    $gResult = json_decode($result, true);
    if ($gResult['success']) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function yourForm(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

    $vars = $request->postVars();
    if (!$this->checkGoogle_recaptcha_Response($vars['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        // throw error
    } else {
        //not a robot, do something with request
    }
}
```