# Google captcha isnt working on silverstripe code

Tags: php, recaptcha, silverstripe

In the below code the captcha is coming and after proving we are not robot nothing happened. I have added both public and private key too.

Also, the captcha tool is coming above the header in it if adding any hidden field an error occur.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='https://www.g**le.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

class ContactPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = array(
        'TelCustomerSupport'    => 'Varchar',
        'TelProjectSupport'     => 'Varchar',
        'OfficeName'            => 'Text',
        'OfficeStreetAddress'   => 'Text',
        'OfficeAddressLocality' => 'Text',
        'OfficePostalCode'      => 'Varchar',
        'OfficeMapLink'         => 'Text',
        'OfficeLatitude'        => 'Text',
        'OfficeLongitude'       => 'Text',
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        // Add extra fields
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('TelCustomerSupport', 'Phone - Customer, Trade & Retail Support'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('TelProjectSupport', 'Phone - Project Support'), "Content");

        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeName'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeStreetAddress'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeAddressLocality'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficePostalCode'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeMapLink'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeLatitude'), "Content");
        $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", new TextField('OfficeLongitude'), "Content");

        return $fields;
    }

}





class ContactPage_Controller extends NetSuitePage_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array('ContactForm');

    // Generate the form
    public function ContactForm()
    {
        // Create fields
        $fields = new FieldList(
            TextField::create("FirstName")->setTitle(_t('Contact.FIRSTNAME')),
            TextField::create("LastName")->setTitle(_t('Contact.LASTNAME')),
            EmailField::create("Email")->setTitle(_t('Contact.EMAILADDRESS')),
            TextField::create("Phone")->setTitle(_t('Contact.PHONENUMBER')),
            DropdownField::create('Iam', _t('Contact.IAMA'), $this->translateNetsuiteConfigArray('Contact', 'Iam')),
            TextField::create("SendSubject")->setTitle(_t('Contact.SUBJECT')),
            HoneyPotField::create("Subject2")->setTitle('Subject2'),
            TextareaField::create("Message")->setTitle(_t('Contact.MESSAGE'))->setColumns(30)->setRows(10)
        );




        // Create actions
        $submitbutton = new FormAction('doContactForm', _t('Contact.SEND'));
        $submitbutton->addExtraClass('btn btn-black');
        $actions = new FieldList(
            $submitbutton
        );



        $validator = ZenValidator::create();
        $validator->addRequiredFields(array('FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Iam', 'SendSubject', 'Message'));
        $validator->setConstraint('FirstName', Constraint_length::create('max', 32));
        $validator->setConstraint('LastName', Constraint_length::create('max', 32));
        $validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_length::create('min', 7));
        $validator->setConstraint('Email', Constraint_type::create('email'));
        $validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_type::create('digits'));
print"<div class=\"g-recaptcha\" data-sitekey=\"6LdCAxEUAAAAAHSWL1xulOjZLv-6PPHTSQJdjpEu\"></div>"
        $form = new Form($this, 'ContactForm', $fields, $actions, $validator);
        $form->addExtraClass('contact-form');
        $form->setFormMethod('POST', true);

        return $form;
    }
    // Deal with form submission
    public function doContactForm($data, $form)
    {

        $submission = new ContactFormSubmission();
        $form->saveInto($submission);
        $submission->write();

        $data['path'] = print_r($this->refererTracker->retrieveAll(), true);

        $email = new Email();
        $email->setTemplate('ContactFormEmail');
        $email->populateTemplate($data);
        $email->setTo($this->getNetsuiteConfig('Contact', 'Emails'));
        $email->setFrom("no-reply@warmup.co.uk");
        $email->setSubject('[warmup.co.uk] New contact from the website');
        $email->populateTemplate($data);
        $email->send();

        $post = $this->getNetsuiteConfig('Contact');

        $post->firstname                    = $data['FirstName'];
        $post->lastname                     = $data['LastName'];
        $post->email                        = $data['Email'];
        $post->phone                        = $data['Phone'];
        $post->custentity116                = $data['Iam'];
        $post->custentitysubject_contact_us = $data['SendSubject'];
        $post->custentitymessage_contact_us = $data['Message'];

   if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])&& $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
        var_dump($_POST);
        $secret = " 6LdCAxEUAAAAAIss47kbDqOWVaf3H2ruMkgddKTa";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $rsp  = file_get_contents("https://www.***.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");
        var_dump($rsp);
        $arr = json_decode($rsp,TRUE);
        if($arr['success'])
{


        // Check for success
        if ($this->queueNetSuitePost($post)) {
            return $this->redirect(Director::get_current_page()->Link()."?success=1");
        }
}

else{
        // Redirect back with form data and error message
        Session::set('FormInfo.' . $form->FormName() . '.data', $data);
        Session::set('FormInfo.'.$form->FormName().'.errors', array());
        $form->sessionMessage("Netsuite error", 'bad');

        return $this->redirectBack();
}
    }



}

 // Returns true if form submitted successfully
    public function Success()
    {
        return isset($_REQUEST['success']) && $_REQUEST['success'] == "1";
    }

    public function getCurrentSubsite()
    {
        $subsite = Subsite::currentSubsite();

        if($subsite) {
            return $subsite->Title;
        }
        return $subsite;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you literally put that code into a template, exactly in your example?

Comment: Have a look at the following answer on how to add Google's NoCaptcha to a SilverStripe form:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536338/add-google-recaptcha-on-a-silverstripe-form#answer-41684039

Answer (score 2):

"print" or "echo" will render immediately. The rest of your code/template won't render until later. If you want to insert html you are better off adding a LiteralField to your form.

What might be even better is using a module which provides recaptcha in an easy to use form field, e.g. https://github.com/Level51/silverstripe-recaptcha

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.. but should i upload whole folder in root or just copy the coe to create captcha is suffi

Comment: yntax error, unexpected '$captcha' (T_VARIABLE) is coming

Comment: Sir it still not working i have removed abv error by including Recaptcha file but still whether i select captcha or not form in submitting

Comment: Normally you would load the whole module using composer (composer require level51/silverstripe-recaptcha. If you're not using composer to manage your dependencies, I highly recommend looking into it. You would then run a dev/build, then the SilverStripe autoloader will pick up the new class.